# IIS Silverlight not connecting to WCF

Tags: wcf, silverlight, iis-6

I am at a loss, and hoping someone here can help me.  I have created a WCF service that runs on a remote computer.  The service is self-hosted, but provides the clientaccesspolicy.xml through a webget command.

I also have a silverlight application that queries the WCF server. I access the service through a service reference.  When I execute the silverlight code in VS2008 it connects fine to the server.  When I host the site on a local IIS server (even 5.1) it works fine.

However, when I move my site to our official IIS server, the client dies when it tries to connect to the server.  Initially it did not work at all, then we had the MIME types added. Although, currently, I think the MIME type for .xap is still set to application/octet-stream. (Don't know if it really makes a difference, since the site gets downloaded now.)

I checked the packets going in and out of the browser, and it seems that the client crashes every time I try to establish a connection to the server (I believe it takes place when it instantiates the connection code, before even sending a packet.) I know the IIS server can see the WCF Service, since I tested retrieving data from the service using ASP.NET.

Other than installing the SDK on that IIS, I can think of nothing else to try.  Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is likely the ClientAccessPolicy.xml location.  Where is it in relation to the domain?  It has to be at the root of the domain server (http://domain.com/clientpolicyfile.xml or http://www.domain.com/clientpolicyfile.xml).

Comment: Thanks Shawn, however, I went to my http://domain/clientaccesspolicy.xml and got the right file

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say that I answered my own question, but in the end I moved the WCF service to an IIS environment, and all of a sudden, the communication worked fine.